# EPSON thermal printer cuts paper berfore document complete

Tags: java

I am using EPSON thermal printer for billing software. I am using **java & jasper report** for programming and reporting. In jasper report I set properties **"Ignore Pagination=true"** and custom paper size to **Roll Paper 80mm * 297mm.** And In printer setting printing preferences set to default "Document(Feed, Cut)".

But problem is, **on printing bill, paper cuts on 297mm page height and before document ends.**

I tried exporting report to pdf format and then printing, but problem remains same.
Please help...

Narhari

Answer (score 1):

```
Try using 

Ignore Pagination=false
Float columnfooter = false
summery onnewpage = false
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is paper size: "Roll Paper 80mm * 297mm", with that paper size it will only print up to 297mm. You should set it to "Roll Paper 80 x 3276 mm" for bigger documents.